# Representing a Floating Point with Discriminated Unions and Record Types

Tags: f#, floating-point, record, domain-model, discriminated-union

For my project, it’s necessary to “decompose” [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) floating point types into an internal representation. I have the following types:

```
type Sign =
   | Positive
   | Negative
type Number =
   { exponent: int32 // The exponent is de-biased when converting from floating-point types. Exponent values here range from −2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.
     mantissa: bigint } // There is no implicit leading 1 bit. If the original float was normal, the converting code prepends the originally hidden 1 bit to the mantissa. Subnormals do not have this bit prepended to the mantissa.
type Infinity = Infinity
type SuperFloat =
   | Number of Sign * Number
   | Infinity of Sign * Infinity
   | NaN
```

Could this have been better written using some syntactic shortcut to save on types, or is this the minimal amount of types I have to put up with to cover all the possible kinds of floats?

- [NaN payloads](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33967804/1405571) do not need to be supported.
- The internal representation is not exposed to outside code and require no interoperability with other .NET languages.

Comment: IEEE has subnormals too.

Comment: @FuleSnabel These floats come from a number of sources. They could be *binary16* (half-precision), *binary64* (double-precision), or even *binary128* (quad-precision). My understanding is that the subnormals just map to normal numbers. When converting back to a native floating point type, if subnormal representation is required, then it will be used.

Comment: The subnormals do map. From the description my impression was that you wanted to create a model of IEEE floating point numbers as is. Anyway, should work fine as long as you use the mantissa to shift the bigint by power of 2 (as the standard float is a binary number not a decimal number)

Answer (score 4):

First, the `Infinity` type is not really useful: because it only has one value, it doesn't encode any information.

Then, you don't need `Sign` under the `Number` case, because number itself has sign "baked in" - i.e. mantissa can be negative (by the way, for this reason your representation is not just overkill, but actually *incorrect*).

So the second iteration would be:

```
type Sign = 
   | Positive 
   | Negative 
type Number = { 
   exponent: int32 
   mantissa: bigint } 
type SuperFloat = 
   | Number of Number 
   | Infinity of Sign
   | NaN
```

The next point is arguable and depends on intended usage, but I personally would get rid of the `Sign` type and encode the infinity sign with two separate cases instead:

```
type Number = { 
   exponent: int32 
   mantissa: bigint } 
type SuperFloat = 
   | Number of Number 
   | PositiveInfinity
   | NegativeInfinity
   | NaN
```

And finally, you could bring the exponent and mantissa directly under the DU if you want, but that one is even more arguable and even more depends on usage:

```
type SuperFloat = 
   | Number of exponent: int32 * mantissa: bigint
   | PositiveInfinity
   | NegativeInfinity
   | NaN
```

---

### Update

Since I was reminded in the comments that negative zero is a thing, I have to bring back the `Sign` type after all. And since it's here anyway, we can use it for infinity, too:

```
type Sign = Positive | Negative
type SuperFloat = 
   | Number of sign: Sign * exponent: int32 * mantissa: bigint
   | Infinity of Sign
   | NaN
```

**However**, keep in mind that this type allows incorrect values, because the mantissa can still be negative. Unfortunately, `bigint` can't be made non-negative.

I assume there is a reason for making mantissa a `bigint` (do you need to work with arbitrarily large numbers?), but if there is no specific reason, I would recommend going with `uint64` instead. It will be more than enough to encode double-precision floating-point numbers.

Comment: What about negative 0? This is something IEEE floats has in order to handle division by -Inf correctly.

Comment: @FuleSnabel Thanks for reminding me. I almost forgot why I did not accept this answer immediately. The internal *intermediate* representation is supposed to make it easy to fiddle with the parts of value, which means the sign should be kept separate and the mantissa always ≥ 0. That simplifies expressions where I am `>>>`-ing the mantissa.

And yeah. `−0` must also be in the domain to support other IEEE 754 behaviors.

Comment: That aside, I was actually able to tighten the code to just two types (`Sign` and `SuperFloat`) while keeping the sign separate thanks to the last iteration in the answer.