# Will the byte representation of 0/0 (NAN) and 1/0 (INF) be the same on any C compiler and machine?

Tags: c, math

As far as I've understood, you can get `NaN` and `Inf` by doing this:

```
// this is no code, just IEEE-754 math
n = 0 / 0
i = 1 / 0
```

Now, you can examine the byte representation of the two variables like so:

```
void dumpdouble(double x) {
    unsigned char *p = (unsigned char *) &x;
    int k;
#ifndef BIG_ENDIAN
     for(k = 0; k < 8; k++) printf("%.2x", p[7-k]);
#else    
     for(k = 0; k < 8; k++) printf("%.2x", p[k]);
#endif 
    printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    double n = (double) 0 / (double) atoi(argv[1]);
    double i = (double) 1 / (double) atoi(argv[1]);     
    dumpdouble(n);
    dumpdouble(i);
    return 0;
}
```

Start the program like this:

```
./a.out 0
```

On Windows 7 with Visual C 15 for x64 the result is this:

```
fff8000000000000
7ff0000000000000
```

Now what I'm wondering is this:

Is 0/0 using 64-bit doubles guaranteed to deliver `$fff8000000000000` and is 1/0 using 64-bit doubles guaranteed to deliver `$7ff0000000000000` on any IEEE-754-compliant C compiler and architecture or is that machine-/compiler-/whatever-specific and I cannot rely on those divisions yielding the results presented above?

Comment: `1/0` and `0/0` are integer divisions which cause Undefined Behavior.

Comment: @Ayxan, so the answer is no :).

Comment: @BartFriederichs Well, posted as an answer because of your comment :)

Comment: First, you need to fix the integer arithmetic problem. Then, being IEEE-754 compliant does not guarantee a C implementation maps `double` to the IEEE-754 binary64 format—it could be binary128 or even a decimal format. Optional Annex F of the C standard does guarantee this. Let’s assume that. Byte ordering is not guaranteed to be big-endian or little-endian. It could be mixed. (E.g., an implementation might be little-endian within a four-byte word but store words in a big-endian order.) It is very common you will get the results you show, but it is not guaranteed.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Please check updated code.

Comment: More interesting (to me) is why the two results of division by zero are different. In the case of `1.0 / 0.0` the result is +infinity, but the result of `0.0 / 0.0` is indeterminate.

Comment: @WeatherVane isn't it the same in mathematics?

Comment: @Ayxan it is *because* of mathematics, and that the floating point format can represent it (unlike standard integer types).

Comment: @Ayxan no, 1/0 is as much garbage as is 0/0.

Comment: @WeatherVane  In IEEE-754, finite_non_zero/zero as in `a/z` is `sign_of_a ^ sign_of_z infinity`.

Comment: @chux yes I know the sign is handled, so `1.0 / -0.0` gives -infinity, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With IEEE-754 math there is only 1 encoding for +INF and 1 for -INF.  So `./a.out 0` would be expected to yield just the one +INF encoding for `1/(double)0`.  Depending on endian of the *double*, ( which may differ from the endian of `int`) the byte sequence may differ. As `BIG_ENDIAN` definition is not shown, it can only be hoped to be correct for *double*.  Note that a rare machine could use something other than big/little encoding.

There are many encodings for Not-a-Number.  `fff8000000000000` is  one of them.  Other compliant compilers/runs may yield other results.  e.g. The [payload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33967804/what-uses-do-floating-point-nan-payloads-have) may differ.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it's about the byte representation of NaN and INF. Of course, Ayxan is also right that strictly speaking, dividing by 0 is undefined in C (although all compilers I have tried seem to yield INF and NaN in the case presented above, but of course it's not guaranteed then)

Answer (score 8):

`0 / 0` and `1 / 0` are integer divisions, which cause undefined behavior, thus no guarantees are given.

> C11 6.5.5p5 - The result of the / operator is the quotient from the
>   division of the first operand by the second; the result of the %
>   operator is the remainder. In both operations, if the value of the
>   second operand is zero, the behavior is undefined.