# Difference between NA_real_ and NaN

Tags: r, nan, na

When I use `.Internal(inspect())` to `NA_real_` and `NaN`, it returns,

```
> .Internal(inspect(NA_real_))
@0x000001e79724d0e0 14 REALSXP g0c1 [REF(2)] (len=1, tl=0) nan
> .Internal(inspect(NaN))
@0x000001e797264a88 14 REALSXP g0c1 [REF(2)] (len=1, tl=0) nan
```

It seems like their only difference is the memory address.

However, when I coerce the `NA_real_` and `NaN` into character, it returns,

```
> as.character(c(NaN, NA_real_))
[1] "NaN" NA
```

I understand that it should return the above result as `NaN` can't be character and it will be coerced into `"NaN"` but `NA_real` will be coerced into `NA_character_`. But considering their gut is same, how can R returns different results for them?

Thank you in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well. First off, remember that `NA` is an R concept that has no equivalent in C. So, by necessity, `NA` needs to be represented differently in C. The fact that `.Internal(inspect())` does not make this distinction doesn’t mean it isn’t made elsewhere. In fact, it so happens that `.Internal(inspect())` uses `Rprintf` to print the value’s internal double floating point representation. And, indeed, R NAs are encoded as an NaN value in a C floating point type.

Secondly, you observe that “their only difference is the memory address.” — So what? At least *conceptually,* distinct memory addresses are fully sufficient to distinguish NA and NaN, nothing more is required.

But as a matter of fact R distinguishes these values by a different route. This is possible because the [IEEE 754 double precision floating point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) has [multiple different representations of NaN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Floating_point), and R reserves a specific one for NAs:

```c
static double R_ValueOfNA(void)
{
    /* The gcc shipping with Fedora 9 gets this wrong without
     * the volatile declaration. Thanks to Marc Schwartz. */
    volatile ieee_double x;
    x.word[hw] = 0x7ff00000;
    x.word[lw] = 1954;
    return x.value;
}
```

and:

```c
/* is a value known to be a NaN also an R NA? */
int attribute_hidden R_NaN_is_R_NA(double x)
{
    ieee_double y;
    y.value = x;
    return (y.word[lw] == 1954);
}

int R_IsNA(double x)
{
    return isnan(x) && R_NaN_is_R_NA(x);
}

int R_IsNaN(double x)
{
    return isnan(x) && ! R_NaN_is_R_NA(x);
}
```

(`src/main/arithmetic.c`)

Comment: It's also worth mentioning something from the documentation:  "Numerical computations using NA will normally result in NA: a possible exception is where NaN is also involved, in which case either might result (which may depend on the R platform). However, this is not guaranteed and future CPUs and/or compilers may behave differently."  This is because the 1954 value in NA isn't guaranteed to be kept through all operations.

Comment: @Konrad Thank you for your reply! It really helps me a lot. But I'm confused about the second paragraph. When we use .Internal(inspect(NaN)) twice, we'll get different memory address as well. As I haven't learnt C before, what I can think is that the new NaN is stored at different location compared with the previous NaN but they are same internally. So I'm not sure why 'distinct memory addresses are fully sufficient to distinguish NA and NaN'. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: @YuliS OK, that makes it indeed harder (it would still be possible to use the memory address to distinguish the values, e.g. by internally maintaining a hash table, but that would either complicate the logic or be inefficient). The second paragraph in my answer was written under the assumption that the `NaN` and `NA` literal values would be singletons, i.e. always be at the same memory address. The fact that R doesn’t do this is actually a bit surprising (using the same memory address for such objects is a fairly frequent memory optimisation).

Comment: `R_NaN_is_R_NA(double x)` isn't inspecting the memory address of `x`. It's inspecting the bit sequence, which varies among the IEEE 754 NaN types. That is how R's `NaN` and `NA_real_` are distinguished. These constants _cannot_ have a fixed address because the elements of double vectors are stored contiguously in memory.

Comment: @MikaelJagan Yes, my answer is already saying as much. And in particular I’m not saying that addresses *are* used to distinguish the values, but that they conceptually *could* be used. You’re right that this would require non-contiguous vectors which would be problematic — but it *is* conceivable (and other languages do something equivalent).

Comment: Yes, and R _does_ use fixed memory addresses for strings, via the [`CHARSXP` cache](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#The-CHARSXP-cache). That is why `object.size(rep("a very long string", n))` doesn't scale with `n` quite as fast as you might expect.

Answer (score 9):

`NA` is a *statistical* or *data integrity* concept: the idea of a "missing value". Eg if your data comes from people filling in forms, a bad entry or missing entry would be treated as `NA`.

`NaN` is a *numerical* or *computational* concept: something that is "not a number". Eg 0/0 is `NAN`, because the result of this computation is undefined (but note that 1/0 is `Inf`, or infinity, and similarly -1/0 is `-Inf`).

The way that R handles these concepts internally isn't something that you should ever be concerned about.