# Why NaN/NA is NaN?

Tags: r

```
R> 1/NA
[1] NA
R> NaN/NA
[1] NaN
```

A number divided by NA is NA. NaN is not even a number. So it is more reasonable to define NaN divided by NA as NA.

I don't understand the logic of defining it as NaN. Is it a careful design choice of R? Or it is just a haphazard choice that was stuck at the birth of R or S.

I don't need any guessed answer to this question. I need an authoritative answer from the original designers of R that carefully thought about this case.

Comment: What I mean is that the answer should be authoritative. It could be answered by the original designer of R but at some other places. An answer posted at SO based on that original source is OK. The current answer by MikeJagan is not satisfactorily answering my question. It merely explains what it is not why it is like this. I don't think this answer can be answered satisfactorily without input from the original designer of R who determine this feature.

Answer (score 10):

You could just consult the documentation, written by R's maintainers. From `?NaN`:

> Computations involving `NaN` will return `NaN` or perhaps `NA`: which of those two is not guaranteed and may depend on the R platform (since compilers may re-order computations).

On my machine, the following return `NA_real_`, *not* `NaN`:

```r
NaN / NA
NA / NaN

NaN / NA_integer_
NA_integer_ / NaN

NaN / NA_real_
NA_real_ / NaN
```

#### Internals, performance, etc.

At C level, `NaN` and `NA_real_` are two types of IEEE 754 `NaN`s, distinguished only by the bits in the significand field of the `double`. Meanwhile, `NA` and `NA_integer_` are both `INT_MIN`.

To ensure that arithmetic involving `NaN` produces consistent results across platforms, R would need to do the following for *every* operation `z = a <op> b`:

- Check whether `z` is `NaN`.

  - If it is, check whether `z` is an `NaN` of the desired type.

    - If it isn't, set `z` equal to an `NaN` of the desired type.

These checks would incur an unacceptable performance cost.

Ultimately, the current behaviour is a compromise, favouring speed over consistency. It is left to users and package developers to decide whether consistency is important enough to justify doing something like:

```r
z <- a + b
z[is.nan(z)] <- NA
```

Considering that most users rarely encounter `NaN` and that most packages don't attempt to distinguish it from `NA_real_`, I would say that this design makes a lot of sense.

#### References

FWIW, here are four related threads:

- *NA_real_ <op> NaN -> NA or NaN, should we care?*, R-devel, Apr 2009 [[1]](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2009-May/053242.html) [[2]](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2009-April/053239.html)
- *Question re: NA, NaNs in R*, R-devel, Feb 2014 [[3]](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2014-February/068371.html)
- *1954 from NA*, R-devel, May 2021 [[4]](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2021-May/080732.html)
- *Difference between NA_real_ and NaN*, Stack Overflow, Dec 2021 [[5]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70471859)

The first three received several comments from members of the R Core Team. [R-devel](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-devel) is a better forum for these kinds of questions, in general...

Comment: Note that `NA/NaN` is `NA` and `NaN/NA` is `NaN`, so the order of the arguments passed to the R parser for binary arithmetic operations seems to determine the result.

Comment: That does not anwser why NaN/NA should return NaN. I'd think R could be made so that it is always NA no matter what the underlying architecture is. I don't think  it makes sense to return NaN. Also, making the result dependent on architecture is a bad design choice.

Comment: Checking the `NaN` type at C level would dramatically slow down basic arithmetic operations.